rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding
I want to know what "rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding" does. Is the below Target Result correct?
To get the below target result, they have used this below statement where 'Value' is a column name.
, sum(VALUE) over(partition by (COUNTRY_CODE, ID) order by Date rows between 7 preceding AND 1 preceding) as 7D_Spend

Here are the results from source and target tables.
Source result:



Date
ID
Value
country




2018-07-30
01
6037.2
US


2018-11-05
01
971.02
US


2018-11-12
01
1915.06
US


2019-01-17
01
5074.01
US


2019-07-17
01
7659.21
US


2021-02-09
01
2867.45
US


2021-10-07
01
2884.65
US



Target result:



Date
ID
Value
7D_Spend
Country




2018-07-30
01
6037.2
null
US


2018-11-05
01
971.02
null
US


2018-11-12
01
1915.06
971.02
US


2019-01-17
01
5074.01
null
US


2019-07-17
01
7659.21
null
US


2021-02-09
01
2867.45
null
US


2021-10-07
01
2884.65
null
US




https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic#sliding-window-frame-it works by rows, not values. For that you want the RANGE frame https://sqlperformance.com/2022/07/t-sql-queries/emulating-the-groups-window-frame-option but RANGE is not supported unless you use UNBOUNDED

@Charlieface I have edited the Target Result. Could you please explain in simple terms if the 7D_Spend column in Target Result is correct ?

No the code above will not generate that. I linked an article showing how to solve the RANGE problem with a bounded frame.

@Charlieface sorry I forgot to mention sum(Value) in the above code.
